# Spring Boot change date format of request param field as DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, dto, localdate

My controller has a `GET` endpoint which accept lots of query parameters. So, instead of having multiple `@QueryParam` I created a `CriteriaDTO` in order to perform dynamic queries to our Mongo database

My controller endpoint :

```
@GetMapping
public List<MyObject> getAll(@Valid CriteriaDTO criteriaDTO){
    return myObjectService.findAll(criteriaDTO);
} 

public class CriteriaDTO {

    private int offset = 0
    private int limit = 20
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate minDate

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

And, I want to pass the minDate is the URL with the following format `yyyy-MM-dd` but I need to convert it to the following format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

My question is : Is there any annotation or something else which accepts the first format `yyyy-MM-dd` and automatically convert it to another ?

To be clear if I make the following call :

`http://localhost:8080/api/myobject?minDate=2020-01-01`

And then `criteriaDTO.getminDate()` will return `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00.000`

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a more simple way than searching an annotation-magic solution.

Just add to your CriteriaDTO an additional getter for LocalDateTime:

```
public LocalDateTime getMinDateTime() {
    return this.minDate.atTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and use it wherever you need time instead of date.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [atStartOfDay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) instead of converting this `2020-01-01` to `2020-01-01'T'00:00:00.000` using custom deserializer. And also since you are manipulating the input data i would recommend to do it as separate operation

```
LocalDateTime date = criteriaDTO.getminDate().atStartOfDay()  //2020-01-01'T'00:00
```

And you can also add formatter [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to get required output

```
date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) //2020-01-01'T'00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Define setter and parse with SimpleDateFormat

```
public void setMinDate() {
    if(!minDate.empty()) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        this.minDate = formatter.parse(minDate)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. Check what you exactly need,

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
    System.out.println(dateTime); //2020-02-04T00:00:00

    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(dateTime)); //2020-02-04T00:00:00

    System.out.println(date.atStartOfDay()); ////2020-02-04T00:00

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime)); //2020-02-04T00:00:00.000
```

You need to modify the getter in dto to format it, for example:

```
class CriteriaDTO {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    private int offset = 0
    private int limit = 20
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate minDate

    public String getMinDate() {
        return formatter.format(LocalDateTime.of(minDate, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
    }

    // getters, setters ...
}
```